# Firestore accessing collection named after UID via flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to create a collection named after the UID right after registration via firebase authentication. Somehow the Authentication UID and the collecten name do not match at all. If i try to fetch the document by the current Users UID "Document does not exist", if i simply copy the collection name - which is supposed to be the uid - it works perfectly fine, but i obviously want it to work for every user seperatly and not just one specific uid.

Document creation:

```
if(_pwController.text == _confirmController.text){
      try{
        _auth.signUpWithEmailPassword(_emailController.text, _pwController.text);
        String uniqueNickname = await _nicknameService.generateUniqueNickname(_nicknameController.text);
        final User? user = _auth.currentUser;
        final uid = user?.uid;
        await _firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).set({
          'nickname': uniqueNickname,
        }, SetOptions(merge: true));
      }catch (e){
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title:Text (e.toString()),
          ),
```

Trying to fetch the data according to the current UID:

```
body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        future: _firestore.collection('users').doc(uid).get(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("Something went wrong");
          }

          if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
            return Text("Document does not exist");
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            Map<String, dynamic> data =
            snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return Text("Nickname: ${data['nickname']} #${data['uniqueNumber']}");
          }

          return Text("loading");
        },
      ),
    );
```

Allready tried everything i could find online, still not sure why its not working or why different ids show up.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.